# AWS MSK (Kafka) LEADER_NOT_AVAIABLE while pushing event to topic

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

I've provisioned MSK, 2 nodes, while pushing mesage to topic get success but with following  warning

```
 18:33:06.318 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1]
  WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] 
  Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1: 
  {mytopic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
```

Any ideas why this can be?
My first guess I need more than 2 nodes.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, there's several possible reasons, including: a general network exception, or the cluster is simply not healthy, or your producer has some bad configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was in automatic topic creation, when topic created automatically with default replication factor of 1 was applied, when I create topic manualy with correct replication factor 3 (same as nodes count) problem went away.